# Multiple clients - server chat application, multiple listeners on the same port are not allowed

Tags: sockets, tcp, client-server, chat

Let's say I am creating a chat (client-server) application intended to use in my local network. I'm thinking about having a server which communicates with clients and multiple clients which communicate only with the server. 
My initial thought was that the server is going to have TCP socket listener as well as each client. The problem arises when I have both the server side application and client side application on the same machine listening to the same port. This is not allowed. The same problem arises with two client side applications running on my computer which cannot both listen to the same TCP port.

How can I solve this problem? What is the common strategy?

Comment: Clients don't listen. Servers listen. Clients connect. The problem you describe doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

The problem only exists if the client apps are binding to a *specific* port that the server app and/or other client apps are also binding to, instead of binding to *ephemeral* ports (which is the usual case for clients to do).

To bind to an ephemeral port, either don't bind at all (`connect()` does an implicit bind), or else bind to port 0 and let the OS pick an available port.  In most cases, servers should bind to specific ports and clients should bind to ephemeral ports, when possible.

Your client apps do not need their own listening sockets to communicate with the server.  They would need that only if they are performing things like peer-to-peer data transfers, etc. And even then, they should be using ephermeral ports, or pre-configured ports (in cases of firewalls, NATs, etc), and can use the server-based communications to share what those ports are with each other while negotiating the transfers.